# Using jQuery ajax to get list element of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a specific portion of another web page via jQuery's $.ajax request (that doesnt have an ID).

Simple example....

Here is example HTML:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Foo 6</li>
        <li>Foo 7</li>
        <li>Foo 8</li>
        <li>Foo 9</li>
        <li>Foo 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And some example JQ:

```
$("#more").on("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'foo.html',
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#list ul').append($(data).filter('#list').html());
        }
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

However, I want to target the ul WITHIN the #list, but if I change the filter to be '#list ul' nothing works. Its driving me crazy. How can I target this  element? I tried using find instead of filter but that doesnt bring anything back either.

Cheers

Comment: `nothing works` means? Can you see any error?

Comment: It means that the filter isn't working I guess. Isn't that `.filter()` function for DOM nodes and your data is a `string` wrapped in jQuery object, isn't it?

Comment: how's your data is coming. Is in `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter()` will only work if the target selector is at root level, otherwise you need to use `find()`

```
 $('#list ul').append($(data).find('#list ul').html());
```

OR following would also work but doesn't appear as efficient

```
$('#list ul').append($(data).filter('#list').children('ul').html());
```

Comment: Try my fiddle, your second solution does not seem to work. I've never really used filter so maybe I'm missing something small?

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vKUD7/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div id="list">
            <ul>
                <li>Foo 6</li>
                <li>Foo 7</li>
                <li>Foo 8</li>
                <li>Foo 9</li>
                <li>Foo 10</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="list2">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

With this trivial code to simulate the data returned from the other page:

```
var data = $('#container').html();

$('#list2 ul').append($(data).find('#list ul').html());

//Doesn't work
//$('#list2 ul').append($(data).filter('#list').children('ul').html());
```

First part of the other answer is also correct, you must use find to traverse an elements children recursively, that will find your div by ID and then allow you to find the ul element inside only that div.

The second part using .filter and .children does not seem to work...

Hope this helps!